Count the number of times a value appears in Excel
I have an Excel sheet that collects the responses from Microsoft Forms.
I would like to have a running total of the number of responses submitted by each respondent.
This is easy to do with static data with a formula like =COUNTIF(D$2:D,D2) and copying it over to each row (assuming column D contains the respondent ID - email).
The issue is that as the Microsoft Form that sends data to the sheet is live, the number of rows is dynamic. Hence the "copying over" of the formula is inelegant, and also would stop working without manual intervention once the number of responses is greater than the number of rows into which the formula was initially copied.
Any suggestions? Ideally, would love if I could have a formula in just one cell, and that automatically keeps working forever.

Use MAP() or BYROW() function to make the formula dynamic as row grow based on form response.

Create a list of your unique IDs and count them:
=LET(
    unique, UNIQUE(D:D),
    count, COUNTIF(D:D, unique),
    filter, FILTER(HSTACK(unique, count), count > 0),
    filter
)

